# Sum column values in a dataframe if values in another column are next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Hello I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'name': ["x","x","x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y","y","y"],
       'a': [3,4,5,11,14,15,16,2,3,4,10,13,14,15],
       'b': [9,8,7,12,23,22,21,8,7,6,11,22,21,20],
       'val': [2,1,3,4,5,6,3,21,11,31,41,51,61,31]    
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame (df1, columns = ['name','a','b','val'])
```

I wish to sum the numbers in the 'val' column if the numbers in the 'a' column are next to one another. E.g. in 'a' you have 3,4,5 (all next to each other) so add together their associated numbers in the 'val' column (i.e. 2+1+3) and then create a new column where the added value is present. The harder bit for me is grouping these by 'name'.

I don't know how well I've explained this, but here is the dataframe i wish to end up with

```
df2 = {'name': ["x","x","x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y","y","y"],
       'a': [3,4,5,11,14,15,16,2,3,4,10,13,14,15],
       'b': [9,8,7,12,23,22,21,8,7,6,11,22,21,20],
       'val': [2,1,3,4,5,6,3,21,11,31,41,51,61,31],
       'sum_val': [6,6,6,4,14,14,14,63,63,63,41,143,143,143]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame (df2, columns = ['name','a','b','val','sum_val'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create groups by compare difference for not equal with cumulative sum per groups in lambda function and pass `Series` to [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`:

```
g = df1.groupby('name')['a'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().ne(1).cumsum())

df1['sum_val'] = df1.groupby([g, 'name'])['val'].transform('sum')
print (df1)

   name   a   b  val  sum_val
0     x   3   9    2        6
1     x   4   8    1        6
2     x   5   7    3        6
3     x  11  12    4        4
4     x  14  23    5       14
5     x  15  22    6       14
6     x  16  21    3       14
7     y   2   8   21       63
8     y   3   7   11       63
9     y   4   6   31       63
10    y  10  11   41       41
11    y  13  22   51      143
12    y  14  21   61      143
13    y  15  20   31      143
```

Comment: this works great can I just ask here 'g' is basically grouping adjacent 'a' vlaues togetehr? and in the second line of code what is the 'sum' doing?

Comment: @DanynPatel - exactly, it is compared values `a` and if difference is `1` groups are created